# Setting Default Applications without a Desktop Environment

Tags: debian, awesome, defaults, tiling-wm, user-default

Since [Awesome Window Manager](https://awesomewm.org/) is mainly a window manager, and not quite a full desktop environment, I don't know how to manage the concept of **default applications**.

Without a desktop environment installed, where do I go to configure which web-browser gets launched upon clicking a hyperlink within an application that simply expects my environment to provide a default web browser for servicing URL clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from `xdg-utils`, using the `alternatives` mechanism will help you. On Debian (and most distros nowadays I think) it's already there, no need to install anything. I'll give you some examples regarding urls, web:

```
update-alternatives --list x-www-browser
update-alternatives --query x-www-browser
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

The last command (notice `sudo`, it makes changes, the 1st and 2nd are view only) will present you a menu to choose the default browser.

Have a look also (--query, --list) on `gnome-www-browser`. Probably `www-browser` too, if you use cli/tui browsers like lynx or w3m.

A bit more advanced, if you need to add an app or change priorities:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /opt/LatestFirefox/firefox 300
```

Higher number, higher priority. You can then run,

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

And you'll see the new app among the choices.

There is a a GUI package, `galternatives` for easier viewing of all the available alternatives. But I don't trust it for making changes, it doesn't always works for me.